# Gulp, Git, Windows: gulp-concat and gulp-uglify causing compiled file to show as modified in git even when it shouldn't be

Tags: git, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

My overall question is how to prevent a concatenated and minified file from being different if the pre-compiled files are exactly the same.

I've setup gulp to use gulp-concat and gulp-uglify to concatenate and minify my JavaScript files. It is working great except git is giving me the following warning every time I compile:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in assets/js/build/source.min.js.
```

Git also shows this file is changed even though it should have no changes.

Here is the gulp task I'm using:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
gulp.task('source-js-compress-uglify', ['source-js-lint'], function() {
  return gulp.src(jsSourceScripts)
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(concat('source.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(jsBuildLocation));
});
```

I get the same problem is I add `{newLine:'\r\n'}` to the 2nd argument concat function. I also tried the following (found on a couple other posts) `{newLine:'\n'}` and `{newLine:'\n;'}` and neither worked.

BTW, I'm developing on a pc.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If git says the file has changed, it has changed. The changed file may not need to be tracked in git. In which case you should look up how to have git ignore the file.

Comment: The `core.autocrlf` setting you've got set up with Git will influence those line ending warnings. What do you have it set as?

Comment: @RobKielty some people say don't track compile and minified files, but I've had instances in the past where I wish I had tracked a file so I could roll it back easily.

Comment: @Whymarrh My overall question is how to prevent a concatenated and minified file from being different if the pre-compiled files are exactly the same.

Comment: @miqid I can check, but the answer is irrelevant to the question. See my comment to Whymrrh above. I'm not asking how to prevent git from thinking the file is changed, I'm asking how to prevent it from being changed if the source files aren't changed.

Comment: Hmmm. Okay. I see where you are coming from but I would bend backwards over a spud to avoid tracking generated files in any *source* code control system. For a fast, in production rollback, consider using soft links but really the thing to do is fix source, re run the build, redeploy.

Comment: Are you deploying to a Windows machine?

Comment: @RobKielty There are other good reasons to track the generated file (deployment is easier, different version of compilers could cause difficult bugs to resolve, etc.), but that is another question entirely. No, I'm not deploying to a windows machine, but I'm developing on a PC.